# Youtube Analytics API 3.0: Get video Analytics

Tags: youtube-api

I have couple of question regarding the API -

1. Could we get analytic for a particular video instead of channel? The API specify only channel -[Channel Reports API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#Channel_Reports.)
2. Should the video/channel have to owned by the authenticating user?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly add filters=video==XXX

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/index#filters

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can. According to the section [Video Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#basic-stats-reports) in the
   documentation for [Channel Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports), you can add the `video`-filter. Just add
   `video==YOUR_VIDEO_ID` to your filters. You can read more about targeted queries and their parameters in the [API-Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query#Parameters).

   This is how my parameters look like in Typescript, using Oauth2 for authentication, in order to get a video's viewcount:

   ```
   const queryParams = {
       ids: "channel==MINE",
       startDate: startDate,
       endDate: endDate,
       metrics: "views",
       filters: "video=="+videoID,
       access_token: oauth2Client.credentials.access_token, 
   };
   ```
2. Yes! I would have preferred some errorcode, but the query will return 0 if the user tries to access data of a video that does not belong to him/her.